# url without a hostname

Tags: url, web, hostname

Is there any difference between:`<img src="http://www.foo.com/bar.jpg" />` and `<img src="/bar.jpg" />`? Is some extra work on a browser side needed in the latter case? Why is it that both work?

Comment: As long as your HTML page is in the same directory as bar.jpg, you can simply specify `src="bar.jpg"`. `src="/bar.jpg"` will look for bar.jpg in the root directory of the site the HTML page is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bar.jpg` is an absolute path refering to the root directory of the website. As such the behaviour should be much the same.

Relative paths like `../bar.jpg` are another matter, but I don't imagine the server will decide to work any harder when it has enough information in all three cases to be very efficient.

The main argument against encoding the full site URL is that you might want to move the website in the future, so that could be annoying depending on whether the paths are hard-coded or not.

The main argument against `/bar.jpg` is that you might want to host multiple sites on the same domain as domain.com/site1, domain.com/site2, etc. which would make the absolute root path a little cumbersome.

Comment: Good point about moving the website. One thing to what you said: _I don't imagine the server will decide to work any harder when it has enough information in all three cases to be very efficient._ I believe a server does not work any harder for sure because it is a browser that has to build a fully qualified url out of a relative path in a current file and absolute path to the current file. Am I wrong? That was the main point of my question.

Comment: That's a good point. My knowledge is limited, but since HTTP is stateless, I suspect you are right. That being the case, at most you are likely looking at one or two `if` conditions in the browser code. A largely insignificant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [nice article](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) I found a minute ago - however, that is fairly basic information. I tend to use the absolute path as, when it comes to server-side coding, you can't always be 100% sure when the page is actually loading from (this is especially common in WordPress as plugins may load into pages etc.). Thus, I find it's always safest to use an absolute path vs. a relative one. However, for front-end coding, I'd say a relative path is a sure bet and shouldn't give you any problems.

Comment: From that article: _"If you want to link to a file in a subfolder of the current folder, provide the file path to that file, like so:"_ `<a href="/pictures/tahiti-vacation/tahiti.html">Read about my Tahiti vacation.</a>`. That seems to be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I would not include the first "/"